# Why is this loop not looking for input until an integer is entered?

Tags: java, try-catch, do-while

I'm trying to get the user to input two numbers, and if an invalid character is entered I want it the program to ask the user to enter a number again. Why is my method of doing this incorrect?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double answer = 0;
        boolean goodInput = false;
        do {
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
                double firstNum = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
                double secondNum = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Which operation would you like to use?");
                System.out.println("For addition,         type add");
                System.out.println("For subtraction,      type subtract");
                System.out.println("For divison,          type divide");
                System.out.println("For multiplication,   type multiply");
                String operation = input.next();
                goodInput = true;

                if (operation.equals("add")) {
                    answer = firstNum + secondNum;
                    System.out.println(firstNum + " + " + secondNum + " = "+ answer);
                }
                if (operation.equals("subtract")) {
                    answer = firstNum - secondNum;
                    System.out.println(firstNum + " - " + secondNum + " = "+ answer);
                }
                if (operation.equals("divide")) {
                    answer = firstNum / secondNum;
                    System.out.println(firstNum + " / " + secondNum + " = "+ answer);
                }
                if (operation.equals("multiply")) {
                    answer = firstNum * secondNum;
                    System.out.println(firstNum + " x " + secondNum + " = "+ answer);
                }
            }catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Thats not a number, enter a number:");
            }
        }while(goodInput = false);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are assigning `goodInput` with new value here: `goodInput = false` instead use `!goodInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following means you are assigning false to `goodInput` and then entire expression gets evaluted as `false`

so 
change

```
    }while(goodInput = false);
```

to

```
    }while(!goodInput);
```

Comment: This worked, but now my catch is printing out infinitely, how do I just make it print once!?

Comment: that means you have an exception for each iteration of loop, what behavior you want to put to user ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand your question, but I want the user to enter an int and if a mismatch exception is caught it should print out tellinh the user to enter a number

Comment: ok so until user enters valid input it should keep displaying error message, and what is happening with this code ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the message to print each time an invalid character (not a number) is entered. The purpose of the code is for two numbers and an operation (decided by a string input by the user) to be entered and calculated.

Answer (score 1):

```
} while(goodInput = false);
```

is an assignment due to the `=` as opposed to `==`. Thus, the loop condition is always evaluated as `false` and the loop does not continue.

You can either make the condition:

```
} while (goodInput == false);
```

which reads as "while goodInput is false"

```
} while (goodInput != true);
```

which reads as "while goodInput is not true"

or

```
} while (!goodInput);
```

which reads as "while not goodInput"

The last one is generally idiomatic for Java programmers and is preferred.